# How to do diacritics insensitive search in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, default-settings

While using local file search or global search in VSCode I want the search, by default, to be diacritics insensitive, that is if I search for `ofertă` it should always match both `ofertă` and `oferta`.

I did not find any way to enable this option, and I think at some point in the past it worked (I am using version 1.38.0 now).

How can I change the **search settings** so that it will always match diacritics?